# Populating a drop down select list with the selected option data from an ajax result

Tags: jquery

I have a Bootstrap modal which contains a form. One of the input's is a dropdown select list, see below. The form is populated from an Ajax call and loads the returned data into the form inputs ready for editing.

The issue I have is the "FromTimeH" input select dropdowns is not been populated with the returned data.

Dropdown select list:

```
<select name="FromTimeH" id="EditFromTimeH" class="timetext" required >
<option selected></option>
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
<option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option>
<option value="8">08</option>
<option value="9">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Below is a snapshot of the ajax returned code:

```
$('#EditFromTimeH').val(result[8]);
var FromHours = result[8];
console.log("FROM HOURS", FromHours); // this displays the expected result, example "03". 24 hors format.
```

How can I populate the select list with the result of `result[8]`?

Comment: What do you get with your AJAX call? Your select seems to be already filled, I don't understand why you want to populate it.

Comment: @ iArcadia  thanks for your reply. I need the selected option to be the ajax result "result[8]" which is the data stored in the data table, the form that loads should contain the data previously entered by the user and saved. The response from the Ajax call for result[8] is "03" as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you set the value of the `<select>` element, it will select the `<option>` whose `value` attribute matches. In your case, `result[8]` gives you the string `"03"`, while in your options there is no matching element with the value of `03`.

You can either:

1. Convert the string "03" to a number, which effectively strips the padded `0` at the start. Pass that into your `.val()` method. You can do `parseInt(results[8])` or `+results[8]` to achieve this.
2. Filter through all `<option>` elements and select the one whose inner HTML matches that of string "03". I would not recommend this method, as the `<option>`'s inner HTML does not necessarily have to match its value.